# MSTest executing all my tests simultaneously breaks tests - what to do

Tags: configuration, mstest

Ok, this is annoying.

MSTest executes all of my tests simultaneously which causes some of them to fail.  No this is not because my tests are fragile and susceptible to build order rather it is because this is a demo project in which I use a Db4o object database running from a file.

So I have a couple of DataAccess tests checking that my repositories work correctly and boom, MSTest blows up.  Since it tries to run all its tests at the same time it gets an error when a test tries to access the database file while other tests are using it.

Can anyone think of a quick way around this?  I don't want to ditch MSTest (ok I do but another story) and I sure as heck don't want to run a full-blown database service so I'll take any way to force MSTest not to run simultaneously or tricks with opening files.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You might want to try using a [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx) and entering in TestInitialize and exiting on TestCleanup.  If your test classes all depend on the external file, you'll need to use a single lock object for all of them.

```
public static class LockClass
{
    public static object LockObject = new object();
}

...

[TestInitialize]
public void TestSetup()
{
     Monitor.Enter(LockClass.LockObject);
}

[TestCleanup]
public void TestCleanup()
{
     Monitor.Exit(LockClass.LockObject);
}
```

This should force all of your tests to run serially and as long as all of your tests pass/fail they should run.  If any of them throws an unexpected exception, though, all the rest will hang since the Exit code won't be run for the test that blows up.

Comment: What do you mean by "an unexpected exception"?  I tried throwing .NET and native (C++) exceptions and TestCleanup() appears to always be called.

Comment: Without checking, I think it is possible to have an exception (say a stack overflow) that would cause the thread to exit without being able to run the clean up code.  In that case the Monitor would never exit.

Comment: On .Net 2.0 or latest, a StackOverflowException will crash the mstest.exe process. IOW the whole thing will simply shutdown and disappear from the list of running processes. In this case, releasing the Monitor or not is a moot point.

Comment: For posterity: see answer from @user3202543 he makes a good point.

Comment: Let's be clear, this is for unit tests. Failing tests should be fixed so I'm ok with it failing hard when test clean up isn't called. It could be an issue for continuous integration, though. Better make sure things are passing before check in.

Answer (score 5):

I had a try using locks in this manner.
What I experienced, however, was that VS2010 does **not** execute the tests in parallel by default, but executes them sequencially, in a single thread. (parallel execution could be switched on, however. But this would not prevent the problem completely)

What I find very disturbing is, that the sequencial execution will take place in arbitrary order, even across test classes!

So for example an execution order may look like this:

- Class A - TestInitialize: Lock will be established
- Class A - TestMethod1: Will execute, OK
- Class B - TestInitialize: Lock will be established
  => Thread will be blocked
  => Complete UnitTests will be blocked! The cause is that there are no other Threads which would go on executing methods of Class A. So the Montor.Exit() will never be reached.

I do not understand why MS is doing so. Other UnitTest frameworks (e.g. JUnit) execute the test methods class-wise. Otherwise there will be some interleaving of SetUp/TearDown method which would cause the chaos described...

Is there anybody out there knowing how to prevent MSTest jumping between test classes?
(Currently I use Resharpers test runner, which behaves as expected, executing all tests methods of one classe before proceeding with the next class)

Comment: Seven - I think one of my co-workers put it best: It's because MSTest is not a Unit Testing framework.  It's a very generalist testing framework that tries to do too many things for too many people and fails at all of them.

Comment: Jep, maybe this is just the all-in-one-thing-solution-paradigm M$ always drives, resulting in things capable of everything, but usable for nothing.
So, probably we do need to switch to NUnit, as some of my colleagues do not use resharper.

Comment: "that tries to do too many things for too many people and fails at all of them." applies to Microsoft as a whole, not just their unit testing  "framework"

Comment: While I agree with you that mstest.exe messes up the order, as a test author, you should not depend on what order the tests are run. Every test should be runnable independent of any other test, and this is the only way you can produce effective test cases.

Answer (score 3):

Use an Ordered Test

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182630(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: Sorry, doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It sure does, an Ordered test runs all the tests in a sequential sequence which is exactly what you want!

Comment: It does, but you have to explain why. Otherwise you are not really answering the question but just giving a suggestion

Comment: Indeed, ordered tests are the way to go.

Comment: Again, it doesn't answer the issue. I'm running VS2015 and tests don't run by the order of the entries in Alphabetical.orderedtest file. I have several test classes and the order is respected only for tests inside a given class.