# MSTest: One thread at a time

Tags: exchange-server, mstest, runspace

I have many 'TestClass' in my project. Each TestClass have many 'TestMethod' in them. These test methods are against exchange online. And exchange online allows only 3 runspaces to be created/active at a given point of time.

But MSTest creates multiple threads to execute each 'TestMethod' within a 'TestClass'. Because of this, I wont be able to re-use (reason is exchange online runspace gets broken frequently and if so, I need to create a new one) just 1 runspace and creating single runspace for each test method is not an option.

Is there anyway I can execute 1 test method at a time ? Is there any alternative. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, MSTest guarantess that every test is executed one at a time in a sequence (except in Load Test scenarii). What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, you can't force *MSTest* to run tests single threaded but there are ways to achieve what you want.

One possibility would be to create *OrderedTest* and add all your tests to it. Ordered test runs one test after another.
It could be a lot of work if you have really many tests, though.

For another possibility please check this post: [MSTest executing all my tests simultaneously breaks tests - what to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700043/mstest-executing-all-my-tests-simultaneously-breaks-tests-what-to-do)