# Visual Studio 2019: Is there any way to prevent parallel execution of test methods in a [TestClass]?

Tags: c#, mstest

I am helping with a big codebase, and I found that  `[TestMethod]` executions might interferer with each other if they run in parallel. I know that this is a bad practice.

Is there any way (like a C# attribute) to prevent parallel execution of all tests in a `[TestClass]`?

The tests are running automated in a few environments, including Azure DevOps. I am looking for a way to solve this matter in c# code and avoid using settings depends on the test runner.

**Update and clarification #1**

I know we have questions like this one dated back in 2009:

[MSTest executing all my tests simultaneously breaks tests - what to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700043/mstest-executing-all-my-tests-simultaneously-breaks-tests-what-to-do)

Fast forward 11 years to 2020, I expect visual studio product family is a diffrent thing with the same name.

**Update and clarification #2**

This is not an NUnit question.
The lazer forcus of this question is MStest.

**Update and clarification #3**

Please note that this is a product (MSTest) specific question.
I know there are many similar questions related NUnit etc. or older version of Visual Studio.

As we know Visual Studio 2019 introduced many testing improvements. That is what I am asking.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, please note the date of the question. After so many years we are taling about a totally diffrent product, same name. Let me add the version number and clarification.

Comment: Could you find a solution? I am facing the same issue now.

Answer (score 3):

Either use `DoNotParallelize` attribute on method/class/assembly, or put  `DisableParallelization` in your .runsettings file.

Ref, and much more about parallelization: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/mstest-v2-in-assembly-parallel-test-execution